# How to fix "String reversing" code in python?

Tags: python

My code for reversing a string works on other websites but is not working on my ubuntu machine on vim.

```
   wrd=input("Please enter a word ")
    wrd=str(wrd)
    rvs=wrd[::-1]
    print(rvs)
    if wrd == rvs:
        print("This word is a palindrome")
    else:
        print("This word is not a palindrome")
```

---

It gives the error:

```
python hannah1.py
Please enter a word hannah
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hannah1.py", line 1, in <module>
    wrd=input("Please enter a word")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'hannah' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `raw_input`:

```
wrd=raw_input("Please enter a word")
rvs=wrd[::-1]
print(rvs)
if wrd == rvs:
    print("This word is a palindrome")
else:
    print("This word is not a palindrome")
```

Now it will work, `input` in Python 2 is the same as `eval(input(...))` in Python 3, however it will try to look for a variable called `hannah`, while there isn't any variable called `hannah`.